# как выполнить bash скрипт когда кто-то соединяется с сервером по ssh

Tags: bash, freebsd

Есть сервер на FreeBSD, на котором скрипт на bash. Скрипт  анализирует файл логов ipfw (на предмет несанкционированного доступа по ssh) и в случае совпадения отправляет сведения на почту. 
Все работает, если скрипт поместить в cron. Но как сделать так, чтобы скрипт работал в реальном времени? 
Пришла мысль запускать скрипт по событию. То есть если кто-то пытается соединиться с сервером по ssh, тогда срабатывает скрипт. 
Но как это реализовать? Есть идеи с inetd(xinetd), но правильный ли так? Или есть какие-то другие способы?
P.S. Задача тестовая. Про fail2ban с его возможностью отправлять почту знаю

Comment: Погугли inotify

Comment: Не понятен предыдущий комментарий. Вы правильно мыслите, надо, как мне кажется, думать в сторону ответа на порту чем-то вроде скрипта-обёртки. Хотя ssh довольно мощная штука, возможно там уже есть хуки.

Answer (score 0):

*ssh* может запускаться как отдельный сервис, так и через *inetd*. Решил запускать ssh через *inetd*.

```
sshd_enable="NO"
inetd_enable="YES"
```

Когда *inetd* принимает соединение, он определяет, для какой программы предназначено соединение, запускает соответствующий процесс. По этому я в конфигурационном

> /etc/inetd.conf

вместо маршрута к демону *ssh /usr/sbin/sshd*, прописал путь к своему скрипту, например */root/bin/test.sh*

```
ssh     stream  tcp     nowait  root    /root/bin/sshd.sh       sshd -i -4
```

А уже в самом скрипте */root/bin/test.sh* запустил код своего скрипта и запустил демона `sshd`

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
#Код своего скрипта, например
echo "Hello" >> /home/artem/test
#запускаем ssh
exec /usr/sbin/sshd "$@
```